# Jenkins Email-Ext ${CHANGES} replace argument

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Does anyone have an example of using the "replace" argument in the ${CHANGES} token of the Jenkins Email-ext? I'm trying to ignore or white out a commit message made by Jenkins as part of the build process and there's no examples of how to do that.

I've tried:

```sh
 ${CHANGES, replace="(?s)^skip_ci*" "test"}
```

but that definitely seems wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You should look carefully at the [documentation for the email-ext plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/email-ext/#tokens) - specifically the section on tokens (which is what you're using).

Unfortunately you haven't specified the context in which you're trying to use this... I assume you're using a Freestyle job in which case it looks like your only alternative is to use a groovy script.  Once you go down that path, you may well find it much simpler to convert the whole job into a scripted workflow (pipeline) in which case you would use Groovy code to manipulate the change log before passing it to the plugin.

Here is a portion of the email-ext document, but it's too lengthy to include it all:

### Groovy script content templates

New to version 2.15 is the ability to use Groovy scripts. Scripts are powerful in that you can hook into the Jenkins API to get any information you want or need. There are two scripts with corresponding templates packaged with this plugin, and it is also possible to write your own.

There are two default scripts and templates available out of the box; one is designed for HTML emails and the other is design for text emails. You can specify which script you want by using the script argument; you can also leave the default script and specify a different template file using the template argument. Furthermore, you can also include a script that does some initialization using the init argument.

...